# Actualizar variable en una funcion de php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

vale, super sencillo, quiero actualizar la variable, pero no consigo el resultado.

```
    $activeServices = 0;
    $canceledServices = 0;
    $completedServices = 0;

    $privateServices = PrivateService::get();

    collect( $privateServices )
        ->each( function ( $item ) use ( $activeServices, $canceledServices, $completedServices ) {
            if( $item['status'] == ServiceStatus::$active ) $activeServices++; 
            if( $item['status'] == ServiceStatus::$finished ) $completedServices++; 
            if( $item['status'] == ServiceStatus::$canceled ) $canceledServices++; 
        });
```

**Objetivo**: llevar un contador de los servicios para cada estatus.

**Observaciones**: No hay error, dentro de la función actualiza la variable, pero fuera, siempre da **0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como nota, el `collect()` no hace falta sobre el resultado de `PrivateService::get();` pues la consulta ya te devolverá una colección.

> Objetivo: llevar un contador de los servicios para cada estatus.

No necesitas iterar para contar, ni el `if` para filtrar. Puedes asignar el resultado directamente a la variable, filtrando la colección con un [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where) y aplicandole [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count), que devuelve cantidad de elementos.

```php
$collection = PrivateService::get();
$activeServices = $collection->where('status','=', ServiceStatus::$active)->count();
$canceledServices = $collection->where('status','=', ServiceStatus::$canceled)->count();
$completedServices = $collection->where('status','=', ServiceStatus::$finished)->count();
```

> Observaciones: No hay error, dentro de la función actualiza la variable, pero fuera, siempre da 0

Siempre da 0 porque es el valor que le asignaste a `$activeServices` en ese ámbito, la `$activeServices` que usas como contador está  limitada al ámbito local de esa función. Podes leer más en [Ámbito de las variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php).

Si por alguna razón, aún quieres cambiar el valor de una variable externa
dentro de la función, podés pasarle a cada variable local de la función, la [referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.php) a la variable original con este símbolo `&`, de modo que cuando se modifique dentro de la función la variable asignada a la referencia, se cambie también el valor de la variable original.

```php
$activeServices = 0;
$canceledServices = 0;
$completedServices = 0;
PrivateService::all()->each( function ( $item ) use ( &$activeServices, &$canceledServices, &$completedServices ) {
    if( $item['status'] == ServiceStatus::$active ) $activeServices++; 
    if( $item['status'] == ServiceStatus::$finished ) $completedServices++; 
    if( $item['status'] == ServiceStatus::$canceled ) $canceledServices++; 
});
```

Comment: Buenisima, muchísimas gracias.